# Unwanted characters being added to url in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to include a simple hyperlink in a website:

```
...Engineers (<a href="http://www.ieee.ucla.edu/‎">IEEE</a>) projects:
```

So that it ends up looking like "...Engineers (IEEE) projects:" with "IEEE" being the hyperlink.

When I click on copy link address and paste the address, instead of getting

```
http://www.ieee.ucla.edu/
```

I get

```
http://www.ieee.ucla.edu/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%BD
```

and when I click on the link, it takes me to a 404 page.

Comment: Everything seems fine with what you have shared, problem could be somewhere else

Comment: That code — http://jsfiddle.net/tjex3/ — does not have that effect.

Comment: Is it just plain HTML or do you use a CMS or something else to generate that HTML ? By the way, be sure your " is a real " (try paste this one in your code)

Answer (score 0):

Check the link. These special character are added automatically by browser (URL Encoding).

[Url Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and it will work::

```
  <a href="http://www.ieee.ucla.edu/">IEEE</a>
```

The proper **format to add hyperlink** to a html is as follow

```
  <a href="(the URL you want to link)">(texts to be hyperlink)</a>
```

and for better understanding go through this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: user2752992 also posted that same link. what is the use of this answer?

Comment: if you include this code this will give IEEE as hyperlink and while clicking on that it will open http://www.ieee.ucla.edu/  url,so i think thats what the question is for.

Answer (score 0):

`%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%BD` represents `â€ž` which is when you get when [a unicode `„` is being parsed as Windows-1252 data](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html).

1. Use **straight quotes** to delimit attribute values in your real code. You are doing this in the code you have included in the question, but that won't have the effect you are seeing. Presumably your codes are being transformed at some point in your real code.
2. Add appropriate HTTP headers and `<meta>` data to tell the browser what encoding your file is really using